# How to add profiles via the FHIR REST api (HAPI)

Tags: hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I've looked at the documentation for creating profiles for FHIR, and I've used Forge to create some xml that I believe is valid to describe a profile.  I can't find in the documentation where it actually states what request I need to make to the RESTful api to actually add a new profile.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guees you need to post a `StructureDefinition`

Comment: Is that done in the same way as posting a bundle, or is there a specific url for structures?

Comment: It should be the same as with other resources. A Bundle should work as well. Use my information with caution. I just started learning FHIR.

Answer (score 3):

You can of course just "store" your profiles on a FHIR server by `POST`ing them to a FHIR endpoint, but you probably mean: can I actively let instances be validated against the StructureDefinition?

There are two ways, both of which require a bit of experimentation to see which public servers support them:

- Any FHIR *instance* may declare it adheres to a StructureDefinition, by adding the canononical url (`StructureDefinition.url`) to the instances `meta.profile` as shown below. Servers may pick this up on a POST and validate the instance against the stated profile:

```
  <Patient>
    <id value="44Q3"/>
    <meta>
      <profile value="http://example.org/StructureDefinition/PatientNL"/>
    </meta>
  </Patient>
```

- Actively ask a server to validate your instance using the `$validate` FHIR operation (see http://hl7.org/fhir/resource-operations.html#validate)

Comment: So posting the `StructureDefinition` doesn't have any effect on the behavior of a FHIR server or is this just implementation specific whether a server uses these SDs for validation or not?

Comment: Correct, posting a SD will not change the behavior of FHIR servers. But as Ewout already said, a FHIR server may validate an instance against the profile(s) listed in the metadata of that instance.